# Data validation to Keep column I cell Empty if Condition Met in column J

Tags: regex, validation, filter, count, google-sheets-formula

Trying to add Data validation in column where  first value before / >139 OR Last value after / >89 then Data Validation will strict the cell to add anything. It would be empty if condition met. I have tried but its not working your help will be appreciated.

```
=OR(IF(TRIM(LEFT(J3,FIND("/",J3)-1))>139),IF(RIGHT(J3,FIND("/",J3)-2)>89),"")
```

[Sheetlink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZIdYKMvHuEhFtsbffbI24L1xqJl33RPLn-Mem5UjZoE/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data validation uses same logic as conditional formatting...

```
=(REGEXEXTRACT(J3, "^\d+")*1>139)+(REGEXEXTRACT(J3, "\d+$")*1>89)
```

[image]

---

> to Keep column I cell Empty if Condition Met in column J

```
=NOT((REGEXEXTRACT(J3, "^\d+")*1>139)+(REGEXEXTRACT(J3, "\d+$")*1>89))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a moment i thought and tried the same formula but it was not working. There might be an issue on the way of applying the formula. But thank you so much.